# Outlook 2013 will not save a new contact

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

I have not been able to add a new contact. When I save the following error window shows up. I run the repair tool but it does not solve the issue

errors have been detected in the file C:\users\charles\appdata\local\microsort\outlook\outlook.pst

Answer (score 1):

Use the ScanPST.exe to scan your PST for errors?

Exit Outlook, search for ScanPst.exe (make sure all folders are un-hidden), run it, Profit?

[How to repair your Outlook personal folder file (.pst)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/272227)

Comment: Can you please specify the path for the scanpst.exe? For example: like OS_drive:\\Outlook\x\x\x\ - at least two levels pls

Comment: Office 2013: c:\Program Files\Office15
Windows 7: Your PST/OST files are typically located at C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\

Answer (score 0):

Create a new PST file, copy everything from the old PST to a new one and make a new PST the default. After that you'll be able to remove and delete the old corrupted PST file.